# webgl / three js shader error

Tags: javascript, three.js, webgl, shader

i'm here to ask you about problems meet in three js.
I try to make parallax mapping.

**vertex shader :**

```
varying vec3 v_pos;
  varying vec3 v_nrm;
  varying vec2 v_txc;

  void main(){
    v_pos = position;
    v_nrm = normal;
    v_txc = uv;

    gl_Position = projectionMatrix * modelViewMatrix * vec4(position,1.0);
  }
```

**fragment shader :**

```
  uniform vec3 camPos;
  uniform sampler2D heightMap;
  uniform sampler2D textureDiffuse;
  uniform float bumpness;

  varying vec3 v_pos;
  varying vec3 v_nrm;
  varying vec2 v_txc;

  float ApplyChainRule( float dhdu, float dhdv, float dud_, float dvd_ )
  {
      return dhdu * dud_ + dhdv * dvd_;
  }

  vec3 SurfaceGradient( vec3 n, vec3 dpdx, vec3 dpdy, float dhdx, float dhdy )
  {
      vec3 r1 = cross( dpdy, n );
      vec3 r2 = cross( n, dpdx );
      float det = dot( dpdx, r1 );

      return ( r1 * dhdx + r2 * dhdy ) / det;
  }
   
  void main()
  {
      vec3 wsViewDir = normalize( camPos - v_pos );
      vec3 wsNormal = normalize( v_nrm );
       
      vec3 dpdx = dFdx( v_pos );
      vec3 dpdy = dFdy( v_pos );
   
      vec2 uv = v_txc;
      vec2 duvdx = dFdx( uv );
      vec2 duvdy = dFdy( uv );
   
      // here will be the POM code
       
      vec2 dhduv = texture2D( heightMap, uv ).rg;
      dhduv = ( dhduv * 2.0 - 1.0 ) * bumpness;
       
      float dhdx = ApplyChainRule( dhduv.x, dhduv.y, duvdx.x, duvdx.y );
      float dhdy = ApplyChainRule( dhduv.x, dhduv.y, duvdy.x, duvdy.y );
       
      wsNormal = normalize( wsNormal - SurfaceGradient( wsNormal, dpdx, dpdy, dhdx, dhdy ) );

      gl_FragColor = vec4(texture2D( textureDiffuse, uv )+(wsNormal * 0.5 +0.5),1.0);
   
      // here will be the lighting and shading code
  }
```

**And i have this error :**

THREE.WebGLShader: gl.getShaderInfoLog() fragment ERROR: 0:? : '' : syntax error

I can't find my error can you help me please ?

Thanks ;)

Comment: post your actual code, not just the shader. SInce the shader works in other places that suggests the bug is in how you're providing the shader to three.js

Answer (score 0):

Did you mean:

```
gl_FragColor = texture2D(textureDiffuse, uv) + vec4(wsNormal * 0.5 + 0.5, 1.0);
```

Comment: thats strange. if I add your code in http://shaderfrog.com/app/editor it works fine.